# How can I solve 404 errors in Laravel 7?

Tags: laravel

I'm making a registration form using Laravel 7, my form has a "preview" step where users first check the details and either submit the details as they are or edit. The actual submission of the details happens in the blade file named `preview.blade.php` and this is where I have placed the form action for posting the data. This part works well, the edit part is the one with the problem as it gives 404 error. Please help.

In my register.blade.php:

```
                 <form method="post" action="{{ url('/preview-details') }}" id="regForm">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="region">Your Region</label><span class="text-danger">*</span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="region" id="region" placeholder="e.g Westlands" required>
                    </div>
                    
                    <label for="start_date">Date</label><span class="required">*</span>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="start_date"  name="start_date" 
                    value="{{ old('start_date') }}" required>
                    
                    <!--Other fields here-->    
                </form>
```

In my preview.blade.php:

```
                <div>
                <a href="{{route('edit_preview')}}">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
                style="float:right;"><i class="fas fa-edit">&ensp;</i>Edit</button>
                </a>
                </div>
             <form method="post" action="{{ url('/client-registration') }}">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="region">Your Region</label><span class="text-danger">*</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="region" id="region" placeholder="e.g Westlands" required>
                </div>

                <label for="start_date">Date</label><span class="required">*</span>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="start_date"  name="start_date" 
                value="{{ old('start_date') }}" required>

                <!--Other fields here-->    
            </form>
```

In my edit_preview.php (this one shows 404 error):

```
                 <form method="post" action="{{ url('/client-registration') }}">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}

                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="region">Your Region</label><span class="text-danger">*</span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="region" id="region" placeholder="e.g Westlands" required>
                    </div>

                    <label for="start_date">Date</label><span class="required">*</span>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="start_date"  name="start_date" 
                    value="{{ old('start_date') }}" required>

                    <!--Other fields here-->    
                </form>
```

In my Routes file:

```
Route::get('/client-registration', 'Auth\Client\RegisterController@create')->name('client-registration');
Route::post('/client-registration', 'Auth\Client\RegisterController@store');
Route::post('/preview-details', 'Auth\Client\PreviewRegisterDetailsController@confirmation')->name('preview-details');
Route::post('/preview-details-existing', 'Auth\Client\PreviewDetailsExistingClientController@confirmation')->name('preview-existing');
Route::post('/edit_preview', 'Auth\Client\EditRegisterDetailsController@editDetails')->name('edit_preview');
```

In my Preview Controller (It works well):

```
    class PreviewRegisterDetailsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }
   
    // Validating the User

    public function confirmation(Request $request)

    {

        $categories = Category::all();

        $request->validate([
            'first_name'            => 'required|string|max:255',
            'last_name'             => 'required|string|max:255',
            'telephone_number'      => 'required|digits:10',
            'email'                 => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users','regex:/^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,6}$/',
            'password'              => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
            'password_confirmation' => 'required',
            'region'                => 'required|string',
            'description'           => 'required|string|max:2500',
            'start_date'            => 'required|date',
            'client_region'         => 'string|max:500',
            'client_category'       => 'integer|max:255',
        ]);

        
        $data = $request->all();
        return view('auth.client.preview', compact('categories', 'data'));
}

}
```

In my edit details controller:

```
class EditRegisterDetailsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }
   
    // Validating the User

    public function editDetails(Request $request)

    {

        $categories = Category::all();

        $request->validate([
            'first_name'            => 'required|string|max:255',
            'last_name'             => 'required|string|max:255',
            'telephone_number'      => 'required|digits:10',
            'email'                 => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users','regex:/^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,6}$/',
            'password'              => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
            'password_confirmation' => 'required',
            'region'                => 'required|string',
            'description'           => 'required|string|max:2500',
            'start_date'            => 'required|date',
            'client_region'         => 'string|max:500',
            'client_category'       => 'integer|max:255',
        ]);

        
        $data = $request->all();
        return view('auth.client.edit_preview', compact('categories', 'data'));
}

}
```

Comment: Before anything, try `php artisan route:clear`.

Comment: You use an a-href-link to editdetails, so this will be a GET request, but your route is listening for POST

Comment: Don't place `<button>`s inside `<a href..`>s. Style your link to look like a button

Comment: @Silidrone I have done `php artisan route:clear` but still get 404 error

Comment: @ brombeer , thanks I will do that

Comment: I think @TobiasK.'s comment answers your question.

Comment: @Tobias K Thanks, How do I fix this? In my edit blade file the data is pre-filled in the form and the submitted.

Comment: @Silidrone, how can I fix that problem now that in edit blade file the form is supposed to submit the data to my database?

Comment: I don't have a quick fix that solves all your problems there. Changing the route is easy, but likely new challenges will arise to keep the data around at all steps. It may be better to save steps in Session rather than carrying through form posts, but that is a bigger architectural change that I don't want to type out in the scope of this question

Comment: @Tobias K, Thanks for the advice, please if possible you can recommend any tutorial or article that can help me understand how to use Session for that task. I'm quite new to Laravel.